# combing red green and blue files to make a .ppm file in a C programme

Tags: c, ppm

i currently have 3 files, a red, a green and blue component file(s) and i need to code a program that will combine these three files into a single readable ppm file. how/whats the best route for me to take for this? thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like this: [rgb3toppm.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/netpbm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/converter/ppm/rgb3toppm.c)?

If you're doing this as an exercise, you can look at the source code for that utility. If you just need the utility, you'll probably find `rgb3toppm` in your `netpbm` distribution.